# Dynamic Hierarchical Router in JavaScript Framework Router

Tags: javascript, javascript-framework, aurelia

We had settled on using Aurelia as a JS framework, but hit a wall with routing.  We have hierarchical navigation, which Aurelia Router does not support (https://github.com/aurelia/router/issues/90).

Navigation also depends on who is logged in, and each path from the primary navigation can have 1, 2 or 3 levels.  Here is a sample of what we are doing now using knockoutjs (we are moving to a SPA): http://jsfiddle.net/22dy9yqw/4/.  The data source for the navigation has to be a nested JSON object that represents the navigational structure, and the UI has to remain as is (bottom level is a dropdown).  Here is an example of our structure:

```json
[
{
    "name": "No SubNav",
    "href": "\/no-subnav",
    "id": "no-subnav"
}, 
{
    "name": "Settings",
    "href": "\/settings\/",
    "id": "settings",
    "children": [
        {
            "name": "Setting1",
            "href": "\/settings\/setting1\/",
            "id": "setting1"
        }, {
            "name": "Setting2",
            "href": "\/settings\/setting2\/",
            "id": "setting2"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "name": "Reports",
    "href": "\/reports\/",
    "id": "reports",
    "children": [
        {
            "name": "Section1",
            "href": "\/reports\/section1\/",
            "id": "section1",
            "children": [
                {
                    "name": "Section1 Report1",
                    "href": "\/reports\/section1\/report1",
                    "id": "report1-1",
                }, {
                    "name": "Section1 Report2",
                    "href": "\/reports\/section1\/report2",
                    "id": "report1-2",
                }, {
                    "name": "Section1 Report3",
                    "href": "\/reports\/section1\/report3",
                    "id": "report1-3",
                }
            ]
        }, {
            "name": "Section2",
            "href": "\/reports\/section2\/",
            "id": "section2",
            "children": [
                {
                    "name": "Section2 Report1",
                    "href": "\/reports\/section2\/report1",
                    "id": "section2-1",
                }, {
                    "name": "Section2 Report2",
                    "href": "\/reports\/section2\/report2",
                    "id": "section2-2",
                }, {
                    "name": "Section2 Report3",
                    "href": "\/reports\/section2\/report3",
                    "id": "section2-3",
                }, {
                    "name": "Section2 Report4",
                    "href": "\/reports\/section2\/report4",
                    "id": "section2-4",
                }, {
                    "name": "Section2 Report5",
                    "href": "\/reports\/section2\/report5",
                    "id": "section2-5",
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
]
```

Can something like this be done easily with Aurelia while still taking advantage of other Router functionality (e.g., mapping)?  Is there a better solution?  I am new to the JS framework world and am a bit overwhelmed.